# no socket io connection being made

Tags: reactjs, express, mongoose, socket.io, mern

All versions installed of socket.io and socket.io-client are the same in my mern app.

Here is my server code:

```
const app = express();

mongoose.connect(MONGOOSE_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
}).then(() => {
  console.log(`MongoDB connected successfully`);
}).catch((error) => console.log(`${error} did not connect`));

const server = http.createServer(app);

const io = new Server(server,  console.log('io is being called'));


io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id)
})

server.listen(3005, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on PORT 3005`);
});
```

here is my client code:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3005'); 
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('you connected!')
})
```

Why doesn't it show the socket io connection was made when I npm start both my client and server?

On my server side, it console logs that:

1. io is being called,
2. Server is listening on PORT 3005,
3. MongoDB connected successfully

Does anyone know if I'm missing anything?

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');
const server = http.createServer(app);


app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000'],
    credentials: true
}))

const io = socket(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true
    }
})

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id)
})
```

Comment: Hey I tried that and still no io connection was made.

Answer (score 1):

1. There is no issue in your code. `console.log('you connected!')` **will NOT show up in server side logs** because it is *client side code*.
2. **You have to check the client side logs** in the browser you are using to open the client in order to view `you connected!`. The shortcut to Dev Tools is F-12 in Google Chrome for example.

Comment: I know this, because the client side logs don't show the socket connection was made from console.log('you connected!').

Comment: if this is the issue, then the reason is that you have not setup CORS. your back-end is not communicating with the front-end for sockets. i.e. the ``const socket = io('http://localhost:3005');`` is not working. Please initialize cors in the server file.

Comment: The issue persists, this is what I already have in my server file. 
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    credentials: true,
    cookie: {
    domain: 'localhost',
    },
  }));
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
 res.setHeader(
 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
 );
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, OPTIONS, DELETE');
    next();
  });

Comment: You did not share the complete code for the server file above. Kindly share the complete codes from now on. But I am happy you got it solved !

Answer (score 0):

The reason it wasn't being made was because my socket.io-client code was placed in an individual js file.

In order for it to run, it needs to be in a component on the client side rendered in App.js.

Once I did that, the connection was made between server and client.